# Checking Seat Capacity on Previous Flights

Tags: tickets, seating

Does anyone know of ways to check the seat capacity or number of tickets sold or number of passengers onboard for past flights?
I'm actually just trying to figure out how many passengers were on a specific flight, not the names of the passengers, just the number of passengers.

Comment: I would think that to be a relatively closely-held secret of airlines. Why do you want to know?

Comment: This is hard to answer without some background. What do you need the data for? What do you want to achieve in the end? Are you just trying to estimate if the flight is going to be full?

Comment: Flights tend to be more comfortable if they are not full, so the OP may well be trying to estimate future loads.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is key competitive information and it's closely guarded by the airlines.  Sorry.

If you just need a rough guess, you can look up past flights on a site like Flightradar24 and then check the capacity of the airplane in that airline's config with SeatGuru, which will give you an upper bound. Then check historical price data with Google Flights: on days/flights that are expensive, load factor will be close to 100%, while on cheaper ones it will be less (maybe 80%, rarely less these days).

However, this assumes normal flight loads.  In 2020 due to COVID all bets are off and many airlines are flying with *much* lower load factors than usual.